# 100% of answered questions

Tags: discussion

I'd just like to draw your attention to the fantastic job that everyone is doing!

We seem to be at the 100% of questions answered all day long, we have lots of answers per question. What this seems to say to me is that what we lack at the moment is users, as we are ready and eager to answer.

Go you guys!

Also, the most interesting questions on the Hot Network sidebar are for this site. (In my bias opinion)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not seek to solicit discussion about the Worldbuilding SE site or its functionality.

Comment: (Just because it's Meta doesn't mean everything goes. :))

Comment: It's funnily ironic this very question has no answers. _(though I guess the 100% counts only main site and not meta, ofc)_

Comment: @Lohoris Might have something to do with the lack of a proper question. We therefore shouldn't count this one :) On a more serious note, these kind of statements are welcome in the chat. Not as questions.

Comment: It's kind of like the congratulatory meta posts on Mathematics.

Comment: @HDE226868 As much as its great that you are reading through the meta site, these posts are over there months old, and this one is even closed! I'm getting pinged by your comments, which are not actually adding anything. Without trying to be rude, unless your comments actually add something new to old questions/answers, you shouldn't be commenting. the only person likely to notice them is the post owner.

Comment: @Mouros I understand. You didn't seem rude, by the way.